# Azure classic CLI with the Classic deployment, Public IP Addresses

Tags: azure, configuration, virtual-machine, command-line-interface

Believe or not, Azure still supports classic CLI with the Classic deployment, even though Microsoft internal people don't even know [where the classic CLI with the Classic deployment API doc is](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/8545be2946030e9913e5063777257960a838d775#commitcomment-31255727).

Because of [the above lack of documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/8545be2946030e9913e5063777257960a838d775#commitcomment-31255727), I'm following the following how-tos instead.

- https://dennisaa.wordpress.com/2016/09/11/azure-cli-creating-a-vm/
- https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines-command-line-tools.md

However, what used to be working, according to above two articles, are no longer working. I.e., it is supposed to be as simple as

```
vm create [options] <dns-name> <image> <userName> [password]
```

However, when I tried that, it only works half the way -- the VM was indeed created, but there is no Public IP Addresses. So there is no way I can access the created VM.

All the docs that I read about the Azure classic CLI, the `vm create` is all that I need to create a vm. So what else is missing here, to make it fully working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure CLI 1.0 for ASM/Classic deployment is still supported as far as i know, just haven't been developed/maintained.

In your scenario it seems you do not have an endpoint.  In a classic deployment IP is tied to Cloud Service, and you need to add an endpoint to re access.  Looking at the example you used you are missing `-r` which should enable the endpoint for RDP.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RykoQ.png]

You can also manually add endpoint using commands below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhH1d.png]